# Which DNS records are safe to delete after setting up iCloud+ email?

Tags: email, dns, domain-name

I'm setting up iCloud+ custom domain email and [Apple instructs to add 5 DNS records](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT212524). I've added them all but I see a bunch of other records that were already there:

- 13 `A`
- 2 `CNAME`
- 2 `NS`
- 1 `SOA`

The domain does not have/require a website, only email. The registrar is Netfirms. Which records must be deleted and which records could be deleted?

Comment: It is good to know that you do not need to delete the other records at all. If you are unsure what they are used for, its a much safer bet to just keep them there. No harm done at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `SOA` record at the zone root is mandatory; the system won't let you delete it. Next to it, `NS` records at the domain root are required because they must match the nameservers configured at the registrar. (This doesn't apply to NS records on subdomains.)

Everything else is *your* DNS records – possibly just example subdomains pre-created by your domain control panel. None of them are required for DNS itself to function (except the aforementioned SOA/NS), but only you can know whether they're required for your own services on that domain.

(For example, if you have some A records on the `mail` subdomain, but if you're clearly not using it in any of your apps – not to mention that your MX records are pointing to iCloud instead of this subdomain – then it should be safe to delete the whole `mail` subdomain.)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answer the SOA and NS records are mandatory as well as the primary A record (the one matching the domainname, or @) The rest are not.

However, in DNS it is not required to remove unused entries. If you are unsure what entries are set for, just leave them be. Only if you add a DNS entry that could conflict with an existing entry, you will want to remove the old entry (or if the interface allows it, change that old entry).

For example: mydomain.ext A 123.45.67.89 already exists
You add: mydomain.ext A 89.67.45.123

The above is valid, but because there are now 2 A records for the same domain and they are different destinations, some clients will be directed correctly while others are not. In such cases you want to remove the old record.

But again, if you don't know what a record is for, and it is not the same as an already existing entry, but with a different destination, its better to leave them be.

If you really want to clean them up, make sure you either make a screenshot before deleting the records or otherwise write it down. That way, you can always add them again if they fail.

Comment: Even the primary A record is not required – not for an email-only domain, at least (OP says there's no website and I assume nothing more fancy either). For mail delivery it would only be used if there were no MX records. But sometimes cleaning up records _is_ a good idea, especially if you're not sure what address they point to; e.g. if I had a subdomain pointing to a VPS, cancelled the latter, and another VPS owned by someone else got its IP address, now they can publish anything under my domain name – rare threat but there have been a few cases in the news (typically for .gov domains, etc).